# Prevent showing movie files after packaging unreal game

Tags: unity, unreal-4

I developed a game which has some videos inside it. I added videos into my project folder so that I can access them.

After packaging, on the folder all videos will be shown as its original format which everyone can play it.

How is it possible on release version no one can go to game folder and play it? Maybe some kind of encryption or change format of file which only its game can play it would help it.

For example when you have a game on your computer, the only way to see the video is that you play the game and you will see relevant videos in the right time. However, after packaging, all videos will be on a folder any everyone can go to the folder and play it and see videos even without playing game.

In Unity after releasing the game, you can't access assets, it will be shown in a file with .resource extension so no one can access it. However, in Unreal Engine, it will show the real file.

Comment: You can access assets in Unity after they’re built, but it’s just a bit more difficult. If somebody wants to hard enough, they will eventually be able to view the videos no matter what sort of encryption you add. If nothing else, somebody else could play through the game and upload them to YouTube. So the question is, why do you feel the need to stop users from seeing these? Depending on how important it is, the answer may vary.

Comment: @EdMarty So true. They may post it to YouTube, but in the game play. There's no game which you play videos without playing it. For example, resident evil, can you watch its videos without playing it?

Comment: I don’t know about resident evil, but there are plenty of games that come with videos I can watch outside the game. Usually these are .bik files (use the Bink video player). A quick glance at my steam folder shows these games with externally watchable videos: Borderlands 2, BioShock 2, Splintercell (various), Lego (various), Remember Me, Rebel Galaxy, Psychonauts, Magic the Gathering, Torchlight 2, Deus Ex (various), Assassin’s Creed (various), Portal 2, Mass Effect (various), Knights of the Old Republic, and others